# Why does NeoVim, Coc, Jedi, Mypy, ... generate some_name.py.[git hash].py files?

Tags: mypy, neovim, python-jedi, python-black, coc.nvim

I have a rather basic NeoVim setup with Coc for working with Python files. My Coc config looks like this:

```
{
  "python.setLinter": ["mypy"],
  "python.linting.enabled": false,
  "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "python.analysis.openFilesOnly": false,
  "python.jediEnabled": true,
  "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": [
    "python",
    "json",
    "html"
  ]
}
```

If I edit a file called `some_name.py` sometimes a file called `some_name.py.[some-git-hash].py` appears beside the original file. The two files are identical. I have no idea why this happens, which process/plugin/... is doing that, why it happens only sometimes and - most important: How I "enabled" this.

What's the reason for this behavior and how can I disable it again?

Comment: I can only speak for Jedi: It's not Jedi.

Comment: Can't reproduce this, what's the `some_name.py.[some-git-hash].py` file location?

Comment: It is in the same folder as some_name.py

Answer (score 1):

You've enable coc's formatOnSave for Python, when you do saving a Python file, coc will clone a new file, then runs your formatter, here is `black`, parses and applies the diff to your origin file.

But I can't reproduce this, the `some_name.py.[some-git-hash].py` file should be deleted after formatting.